# Is there any alternative for explain plan for procedures?

Tags: sql, oracle10g, toad, database-administration

If I am not mistaken, it is not possible to have the Explain Plan for Procedures in Toad and Oracle 10g. If this is true, is there anyway that I can see the cost of my procedures? 
When I make a small change in one of the functions which are called by ProcedureX, the execution time of ProcedureX increases dramatically.
I tried to run each query which exist inside the ProcedureX, but  it is almost impossible due to the huge number of callings and parameters that are passed through them.

Do you have any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DBMS_PROFILER is probably what you are looking for.

**The DBMS_PROFILER package provides an interface to profile existing PL/SQL applications and identify performance bottlenecks. You can then collect and persistently store the PL/SQL profiler data.**

The final HTML report it generates is pretty useful in grouping different function calls,s o you can see where your procedure is spending most of the time (provided you run it with sufficient data).

Take a look at this link and see if it helps.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_profil.htm